# ng generate component does not create ngOnInit and constructor

Tags: angular

I'm following the Angular tour of heroes and when I generate the "heroes" component using "ng generate component heroes" this is my component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent {

}
```

but the tutorial said I should be getting something that looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I was expecting to get the constructor and ngOnInit function and also import the OnInit automatically.
Heres my version if it helps [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xorpu.png)

Comment: It get removed, as they said "most of the users prefer to add this manually if needed." https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0

Comment: @paranaaan Can you add your comment as an answer? I've seen this question pop up a lot more since version 15. It will be helpful to have it in a more visible place. What do you think?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It gets removed, as they said **"most of the users prefer to add this manually if needed."**

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0

Answer (score 0):

Since the latest Angular (v15 I think), this has been removed from the generate component schematic just because it is often unused and adds extra unnecessary code. So if you need them you will need to add lifecycle interfaces yourself.

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0